# Use of undeclared type

Tags: ios, swift

I have no idea why this class cannot be found. I have looked at other post similiar to this , however my naming convention of my delegate should not interfere with swift. I have tried everything I can think of and I still have no idea why SelectButton cannot be found.

Any idea?

[image]

```
   import UIKit
import QuartzCore

protocol SelectButtonDelegate {

    func willSelectButton(button: SelectButton)
}

class SelectButton: UIButton {

    var delegate: SelectButtonDelegate?

    let normalColor = UIColor(white: 0, alpha: 0.2)
    let selectedColor = UIColor(white: 0, alpha: 0.4)
    let recessedColor = UIColor(white: 0, alpha: 0.5)

    init(frame: CGRect, title: String) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        backgroundColor = normalColor

        setTitle(title, forState: .Normal)
        setTitleColor(UIColor(white: 1, alpha: 0.2), forState: .Normal)
        setTitleColor(UIColor(white: 1, alpha: 0.7), forState: .Selected)

        layer.cornerRadius = 3

        bk_addEventHandler({ (object) -> Void in
            UIView.animateWithDuration(0.1, animations: { () -> Void in
                self.backgroundColor = self.recessedColor
            })
        }, forControlEvents: .TouchDown)

        bk_addEventHandler({ (object) -> Void in
            UIView.animateWithDuration(0.1, animations: { () -> Void in
                self.backgroundColor = self.currentColor()
            })
            }, forControlEvents: .TouchUpOutside)

        bk_addEventHandler({ (object) -> Void in
            UIView.animateWithDuration(0.1, animations: { () -> Void in
                self.switchState()
                self.backgroundColor = self.currentColor()
            })
            }, forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
    }

    func currentColor() -> UIColor {
        if selected == true {
            return selectedColor
        }
        return normalColor
    }

    func switchState() {
        if selected == true {
            selected = false
        }
        else {
            if delegate != nil {
                delegate!.willSelectButton(self)
            }
            selected = true
        }
    }

    func deselect() {
        selected = false
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.1, animations: { () -> Void in
            self.backgroundColor = self.currentColor()
        })
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you imported it correctly into the source file that says it can't be found?

Comment: Is that the only error? Does the file whose text you showed actually compile? Is it part of your target?

Comment: i am using swift so i dont need to import anything

Comment: try to restart the Xcode, your SelectButton seems to be ok, you should find it....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I pulled from the repo I was working on, apparently the target was never set. Thus, the file could not be found.